# Transform Arduino Code into C++ with Atmel Studio

Tags: arduino, avr, microchip

I want to use a RTC from Epson, Model: R4543. I found some Arduino librarys and I want to transform them into Microchip Studio. The original Arduino Code is:

```
digitalWrite(_dataPin,(data >> i) & 0x01);
```

and I transformed it in:

```
PORTC |= (((data>>i)&0x01)<<_dataPin);
```

is this correct? It does not work, and I'm trying to find the problem.
The type of data is uint8_t.
Thank you,
Markus

Answer (score 4):

It isn't correct. There is wrong two things.

- digitalWrite setup pin to value 0 or 1. `PORTC |=` can set pin value only to 1, not to 0 if pin value is 1.
- `_dataPin` value can by more then 7. DigitalWrite make transformation to port address and bit position. You can make manual transformation like this. And than set pin to 0 or 1 by simple if construction. Assigned values for `DATA_PORT` and `DATA_PIN` is illustrative only. You do not provide value of `_dataPin` variable.

```
#define DATA_PORT PORTC //maybe not right port name
#define DATA_PIN 0      //maybe not right pin number
if ((data >> i) & 0x01) {
  DATA_PORT |= (1<<DATA_PIN);
} else {
  DATA_PORT &= ~(1<<DATA_PIN);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, now it works! Thank you so much for your help and have a nice day!!!!